# Retrieve Number of friends and date joined Facebook using facebook api - android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to retrieve a set of data from facebook using facebook api in android application. I am able to get the facename and lastname using Profile class. Now I want to retreive number of friends and date joined facebook using the below snippet but I am unable to achieve that. Below is the code snippet of my attempt:

```
System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("--First Name : " + profile.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("--Last Name : " + profile.getLastName());
            System.out.println("--URL Perfil: " + profile.getLinkUri());
//            System.out.println("--Date Joined: " + profile.);
            System.out.println("--URL Imagem: " + profile.getProfilePictureUri(500, 500));
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("--ID : " + profile.getId());
            System.out.println("--Name : " + profile.getName());
```

Please does any one know how can I retrieve the date joined facebook and the number of friends from facebook with the above snippet

Comment: No way to get when they joined. You can get friends by calling `/me/friends`

Comment: how can I get the friends count then. please post an answer

Comment: I did post an answer. I'm not writing code for you.